# How to send data to second viewcontroller from populated html form?

Tags: objective-c, web-services, webview, storyboard

I have been working on this problem for a few days, and it´s driving me totally crazy. I´m using Storyboards.

I have viewcontroller1 with a webview. The webview populates a html login form, through a textField (username) another textField (password) and then a button (submit) which work perfect: once pushing the button, the html form is populated with my textFields input. Once the form is filled and submitted, I want the user to be sent to a new viewcontroller (viewController2) which has a webview, that I want to populate with some of the stuff from the website. I cant, for the world, find out how to send the user to the next view.

Another detail is that the login html form has a user type select. Hence, the adress the submit button sends me can be different. If its a teacher filling out the form the returned address is going to be something like "myschool/jsp/teacher/right_teacher_lesson_status.jsp" and if its a student something else, and if its from another school, something else.

This is the code Ive tried to send the user to the next view containing UIwebview2:

```
- (BOOL)webView:(UIWebView *)webView shouldStartLoadWithRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request  navigationType: 
(UIWebViewNavigationType)navigationType
{

  if (navigationType == UIWebViewNavigationTypeFormSubmitted) {
  UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil];
  ViewController2 *vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"webview2"];
  NSLog(@"Allow navigation to request = %@", request);

  [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];

  return YES;

}
```

The NSLog tells me

> "Allow navigation to request: /myschool/jsp/teacher/right_teacher_lesson_status.jsp"

So if I tell the webview2 the address it will surely pick it up. But since I cant know which school or usertype it is, I want the webview2 to recieve that from the above code. Please help me. How can i pass the info to the next view?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend creating a view with two text fields and a picker menu. This is much nicer than a a web view. If you cannot display the resulting content in a pretty way, you can use a web view, but you should optimize the user experience with custom views whenever possible.

Once you have UIKit elements to capture the data, passing it to the next view controller will be trivial.

That being said:

Maybe this is really a problem of the HTML coding. Your "Submit" button could include the arguments in the URL (GET instead of POST). You can then simply pass the URL on to your next view controller.

```
vc2.urlToLoad = request;
```

As you are not showing the URL, the get variables will not be exposed to the user anyway. As your server can interpret the arguments, you do not even have to parse them in the second view controller (although you could if you need them for other purposes).

Comment: I have created a view with two text fields, the webview is hidden. The submit button is only a button in my view sending java through, stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString. Can I still include the GET function, or do you mean I should change my java method to a webservice?